# socket.io - check how long a person has been in a room

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

**background**

So I'm trying to create a queuing system for my game. I want someone to who has waited for a minute to just be assigned against an AI. I'd also like people who have waited longer to have priority in matching opponents who are of similar skill level. I was wondering the best way to go about this. Should I set a `setTimeout` for the AI assignment and a UTC time to check how long they've been waiting? I'm just wondering how I would cancel the timeout afterwards if they are matched.

timeout:

```
socket.on('waiting room', function (id) {
    console.log("socket has joined the waiting room", id);
    socket.join("waiting room")
    setTimeout(function() {
        socket.leave("waiting room")
        socket.join("some ai game")
    }, 60000)
})
```

Comment: you can use  clearTimeout(); to cancel the timeout

Comment: @Mehari well how will I know which one? If I assign it to a variable, will it be per the socket?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose gameserver resource is limited in game, then players must wait. So when a gameserver is available, we put the player who waited longest to play. Then the logic would look like something below.

```js
const waitinglist = []

//user leave waiting
const leaveWaiting = (socketid) => {
  waitinglist = waitinglist.filter((x) => x.socket.id != socketid)
}

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('waiting room', function(id) {
    console.log("socket has joined the waiting room", id);
    socket.join("waiting room")
    waitinglist.push({
      socket,
      time: new Date(),
    })
  })


  //leave by themselves
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    leaveWaiting(socket.id)
  })
  socket.on('cancle waiting', () => {
    leaveWaiting(socket.id)
    socket.leave("waiting room")
  })
})

//leave by other logic, like match/ai server available
matchResource.on('available', (resource) => {
  const {
    socket,
    time
  } = waitinglist.shift()
  socket.leave("waiting room")
  start_your_game(socket, resource)
})
```

a global waitinglist, you can replace it with a module something like `waiting-manager`

when player enter `waiting room`, enqueue him

when gameserver is available, get a player from queue top, and let him play

whether player quit or begin play, remove him from the queue